Error Integrating React Native Plugin into Main App
Created React Native Plugin with below command
npx create-react-native-library mopo-plugin
Below code gets generated
package com.mopoplugin;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MopoPluginPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(new MopoPluginViewManager());
  }
}


package com.mopoplugin;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class MopoPluginViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<View> {
  public static final String REACT_CLASS = "MopoPluginView";

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public View createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new View(reactContext);
  }

  @ReactProp(name = "color")
  public void setColor(View view, String color) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public static String testMethod() {
    return "Test-method";
  }
}


We can use this in Main React App and Use the plugin
import {
  requireNativeComponent,
  UIManager,
  Platform,
  NativeModules,
  type ViewStyle,
} from 'react-native';

const LINKING_ERROR =
  `The package 'react-native-mopo-plugin' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure: \n\n` +
  Platform.select({ ios: "- You have run 'pod install'\n", default: '' }) +
  '- You rebuilt the app after installing the package\n' +
  '- You are not using Expo Go\n';

type MopoPluginProps = {
  color: string;
  style: ViewStyle;
};

const ComponentName = 'MopoPluginView';

export const MopoPluginView =
  UIManager.getViewManagerConfig(ComponentName) != null
    ? requireNativeComponent<MopoPluginProps>(ComponentName)
    : () => {
        throw new Error(LINKING_ERROR);
      };
export const testMethod = () => {
  const { MopoPluginView } = NativeModules;
  return MopoPluginView.testMethod();
};


Getting this error, what is the problem here?
 DebuggingOverlayNativeComponent.js: Unsupported param type for method "highlightTraceUpdates", param "updates". Found $ReadOnlyArray
I'm in the process of creating a React Native plugin, and I'm facing challenges when attempting to integrate it into my primary React Native application.
Specifically, when I initiate the application using npx expo start, I encounter an error that I've been unable to resolve independently.

I followed all the instructions here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/43678 but nothing worked. I was constantly seeing:
error: node_modules/react-native/src/private/specs/components/DebuggingOverlayNativeComponent.js: /node_modules/react-native/src/private/specs/components/DebuggingOverlayNativeComponent.js: Unsupported param type for method "highlightTraceUpdates", param "updates". Found $ReadOnlyArray
It looks like the team have deployed a breaking change.
To get me back on my feet while the team are fixing it I modified the file node_modules/react-native/src/private/specs/components/DebuggingOverlayNativeComponent.js and commented out the blocks of code that refer to the problematic methods, firstly comment out all lines in the interface NativeCommands block, secondly comment out the method references in the supportedCommands so you are left with an empty array.
This may not be the best thing to do especially if you rely on these methods but I wasted 3 hours getting this working and was getting desperate. Like I say, this may get you up and running again until the breaking change is fixed.
Please note, a npm install will overwrite these changes so you will need to repeat the above if so!
My edited file looks like this:
import codegenNativeCommands from '../../../../Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeCommands';
import codegenNativeComponent from '../../../../Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent';
import * as React from 'react';

type NativeProps = $ReadOnly<{|
  ...ViewProps,
|}>;
export type DebuggingOverlayNativeComponentType = HostComponent<NativeProps>;

export type TraceUpdate = {
  id: number,
  rectangle: ElementRectangle,
  color: ?ProcessedColorValue,
};

export type ElementRectangle = {
  x: number,
  y: number,
  width: number,
  height: number,
};

interface NativeCommands {
  /* +highlightTraceUpdates: (
    viewRef: React.ElementRef<DebuggingOverlayNativeComponentType>,
    updates: $ReadOnlyArray<TraceUpdate>,
  ) => void;
  +highlightElements: (
    viewRef: React.ElementRef<DebuggingOverlayNativeComponentType>,
    elements: $ReadOnlyArray<ElementRectangle>,
  ) => void;
  +clearElementsHighlights: (
    viewRef: React.ElementRef<DebuggingOverlayNativeComponentType>,
  ) => void; */
}

export const Commands: NativeCommands = codegenNativeCommands<NativeCommands>({
  supportedCommands: [
//    'highlightTraceUpdates',
//    'highlightElements',
//    'clearElementsHighlights',
  ],
});

export default (codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
  'DebuggingOverlay',
): HostComponent<NativeProps>);


Hey @ScottFree, I'm new to react native, I've extracted from Expo Eject and attempting to generate it through Android Studio, but I'm encountering this error:
Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
Any suggestions why this might be happening?
Is there any other way to generate APK locally for expo react native app.
